# Question about DAPPS

Tags: dapps

I see lots of Dapps on Ethereum, they say it's decentralized and yet each Dapp is on a domain name with a website, so how is my image that I want to sell in ETH protected?

sorry if this is a silly question for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since the blockchain is decentralized and these are apps that interact with the blockchain, they are called 'dapps'(decentralized-apps), not necessarily because the app itself is decentralized, but rather to indicate that it is connected to a blockchain.